Manually add page number to window.print()
This is my html which is dynamically generated:
<body>
<div class="page-break page" data-div="0" id="printDiv_0">...long content here...</div>
<div class="page-break page" data-div="1" id="printDiv_1">...long content here..</div>
</body>

Now, when printing, I have a working code JS code except, when a div has multiple pages, it only add the prependedHeader to the 1st page, the subsequent pages is empty:
const testx = () => {
    const docs = document.querySelectorAll('.page-break');

    const createHeader = (leftText, rightText) => {
        const header = document.createElement('div');
        header.style.display = 'flex';
        header.style.justifyContent = 'space-between';
        header.style.paddingRight = '10px';
        header.style.paddingLeft = '10px';
        header.style.alignItems = 'center';
        header.style.marginBottom = '0px';
        header.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
        header.style.fontSize = '15px';
        header.classList.add("font-weight-bold");
        header.classList.add("print-header-div");

        // Left column
        const leftDiv = document.createElement('div');
        leftDiv.textContent = leftText;

        // Right column
        const rightDiv = document.createElement('div');
        rightDiv.textContent = rightText;

        header.appendChild(leftDiv);
        header.appendChild(rightDiv);

        return header;
    };

    docs.forEach((div, index) => {
        // Safely retrieve elements and fallback to defaults if missing
        const sectionId = div.getAttribute('data-div') || `Section ${index + 1}`;
        const requestCode = div.querySelector('#RequestCode')?.value || 'Unknown Request Code';
        const lastName = div.querySelector('.print-last-name')?.innerHTML || 'Unknown Last Name';
        const firstName = div.querySelector('.print-first-name')?.innerHTML || 'Unknown First Name';
        const dob = div.querySelector('.print-dob')?.innerHTML || 'Unknown DOB';

        // Generate the eOrderIdentity
        const eOrderIdentity = `${requestCode} ${lastName} ${firstName} ${dob}`;

        // Get total pages for the current div (assuming it has content that spans multiple pages)
        const totalPages = calculatePageCount(div) 
        const currentPage = 1; // For single div context, always start at 1

        // Create and prepend a header for the current page
        const prependedHeader = createHeader(
            `${eOrderIdentity}`,
            `Page ${currentPage} of ${totalPages}`
        );
        div.insertBefore(prependedHeader, div.firstChild);
    });

    // Trigger the print dialog
    window.print();
};





// Letter size by default
function calculatePageCount(content, pageHeight = 1056, pageWidth = 216) {
    let contentElement;
    if (typeof content === 'string') {
        contentElement = document.createElement('div');
        contentElement.innerHTML = content;
    } else if (content instanceof HTMLElement) {
        contentElement = content.cloneNode(true);
    } else {
        throw new Error('Invalid content. It must be an HTML string or a DOM element.');
    }

    contentElement.style.cssText = `
            visibility: hidden;
            position: absolute;
            width: ${pageWidth}mm;
            top: -9999px;
        `;
    document.body.appendChild(contentElement);

    const contentHeight = contentElement.scrollHeight;
    const totalPages = Math.ceil(contentHeight / pageHeight);
    //document.body.removeChild(contentElement);

    return totalPages;
}

Each div prependedHeader will reset on the next div.
For example:
The 1st div has 3 pages, the Header on each page will be Page 1 of 3, Page 2 of 3, Page 3 of 3.
The 2nd div has 2 pages, the Header on each page will be Page 1 of 2, Page 2 of 2.
Same for 1 paged div.
they will all be printed when the window.print() is called.

An example of what's inside one of the <div> would be useful because pagination is more than just calculating the height of content.

@zer00ne, the inside of the div is a complex html table structure, So I didn't add it in my example.

If I understand what your looking for.  You have the const currentPage within the loop, so it will never be anything but 1 for every page.
Add this above the loop.
let currentPage = 0;

Then have this within the loop, before the createHeader()
currentPage++;

Should work better.
